# What is the scientific explanation that 'curing' undead actually harms them?

Tags: zombies, health

I don't understand why curing/healing the undead actually harms them. I always assume that curing is repairing, therefore it doesn't matter if you're undead, if you have damage (i.e wound) you will gain health by being cured. So why is it that they got damaged instead?

Also if that's the case, then how can I actually 'repair' an undead? do I have to harm them?

Comment: If you're talking about the DnD spells, Cure Light Wounds etc..., you're probably in the wrong place, also you need to make that clear and the tag [tag:magic] is in order.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! I am afraid this completely depends on your setting and the way you imagine your undead. For example the classical zombies are just walking, rotting corpses. Giving them medicine, apart from *The Cure*, won't do anything. In some games you have holy energy to heal people - and undead are unholy, which is why the holy energy does not mix well with them. If you are asking about an existing fictional world and canon support for answers you might be interested in our sister site [scifi.SE]. Please take the [tour] and [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: This doesn’t seem particularly world-buildy to me, unless you’re asking for reasons that ‘healing’ a ‘zombie’ in your world would hurt them, in which case we need more information on A: your methods of healing and B: your zombies. There’s a world of difference between ‘why would my divine healing spell hurt the cursed undead’ and ‘why would my nanobot healing goo harm a parasitically reanimated corpse’.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding Rizki. Your question — expressed differently — reads: "What is the scientific explanation behind this **magic**?" Answer: there is no scientific explanation to it because if there was, it would be science, not magic. The **principle** behind it though is — as @Secespitus said — simply that undead are unholy. Holy magic makes living things be well and unliving things be... eh... unwell. This while unholy magic makes living things be unwell and unliving things be well. Undead are simply just some kind of anti-life.

Comment: @MichaelK, to simplify: healing adds points. Add 5 to 10 and you get further away from 0. Add 5 to -10 and you get closer to 0, where the existence finish.

Comment: yeh @L.Dutch I thought the math was a good answer too.  Put it up and I will give you a vote.

Comment: @Willk, I didn't post that as an answer as the question was to be put on hold. If the OP make it such that it can be reopened, and it still fit the question, I will post it

Comment: In DnD cure and healing spells hurt undead because they are positive energy spells, and undead are made of negative energy. This is a DnD concept only, and doesn't apply to zombies from other genres or games.

Answer (score 2):

**Pseudo-scientifically, undeath should be a balancing act**

If there are two natural states for a body, "life" and "death", "undeath" is some perverse suspended state where a body is unable to restore itself to life but not damaged enough to die.  Maintaining this balancing act is some pathogen or curse, and tipping the balance in favor of one state or another would "kill" the undead by causing it to no longer be "undead".

**Healing**

Healing obviously tips the scale toward life by supplementing the body's own ability to self-repair.  However, if the body is already in a downward spiral, healing the body may prolong the undeath state.

**Harming**

Harming is the opposite of healing.  Harming an undead would bolster the pathogen or curse's ability to prevent the body from defeating it, effectively "healing" the undead.  Excessive harm, however, would push the body into an unrecoverable state, killing it completely.

This kind of agrees with how undead are normally perceived, since they can often be both "cured" and "killed", despite being neither alive nor dead.

Comment: Excellent answer. Here is a clarifying analogy: undead is actually a normal human infected with a zombie virus. Healing the human means harming the virus.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like tug-of-war between life and unlife. Adding people to the life side of the rope bolsters them but at the same time weakens the undead side. Adding people to the undead side of the rope then naturally has the opposite effect. For the team that ends up losing, the mud pit in the center is straight-up death.

So to answer your question, you'd pull on the undead (negative energy) side to heal undead and harm the living, and you'd pull on the life (positive energy) side to heal the living and harm the undead.